# Load files in PyPy terminal [Windows]

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pypy

On a laptop (under Windows) there is a file at the address:

```
C:\Users\sebas\code.py
```

What command should be written in the PyPy3 terminal (below) to load this file?

[image]

Comment: PyPy works just like CPython. How would you do this task in CPython?

Comment: @mattip this is the first time I use Python directly, usually I use SageMath where we just need to type %attach file address.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to put the file in the same folder than the pypy terminal and then to write the command:

```
exec(open("code.py").read())
```

Comment: `open(path-to-file).read()` is an anti-pattern since nothing promises you the file will be closed. CPython closes the file as an implementation detail, PyPy will leave it dangling for a while.

Comment: This is better (formatting here does not allow multiple lines):
`with open("code.py") as fid:
    exec(fid.read())`

Comment: @mattip Thanks! What is the problem if the file is not closed?